# How to solve Error 404 Not Found in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

My application url : `http://localhost/ctsubagent/`

My Ajax Code :

```
...
 $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'hotel_booking/hotel/search_hotel',
        type: "post",
 ...
```

When I click button to run ajax, in consolle exist error like this :
`http://localhost/subagent/hotel_booking/hotel/search_hotel` 404 Not Found

It appears that it was not calling ctsubagent, but it was calling subagent. This is causing the error.

It seems like there should be set in the config. But I do not know. I've tried it, but have not been successful.

Any help much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: What is your base url and what is your ajax code?

Comment: @Shomz, I had update my question.

Comment: In your `url: "<?php echo base_url('hotel_booking/hotel/search_hotel');?>",` Make sure your controller class and file name has first letter upper case. You also may need to set your base url in config.php

Comment: where you are assign base_url  variable and what ?

Comment: try with  `url:  "<?php echo site_url('hotel_booking/hotel/search_hotel');?>",`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I heard somewhere that we can leave base_url blank if files are in main root folder......

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes you can but On Codeigniter 3 when you echo it some times will not say the word localhost but instead something like `::1`  and some links may not work because of it. Every computer different may work fine or may run into issue

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Thanks for the info man :)